# MySqL loading local data is disable error , without using terminal commands

Tags: mysql

I got loading local data is disable error. I found many way that could solve by

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;
mysql --local-infile=1 -u root -p1
```

But I am wondering whether I could not use terminal command to fix error.(Just type in MySql query)
I found some way to add into my.cnf

```
[mysql]
local-infile

[mysqld]
local-infile
```

But it still doesn't work.

This is my sample code that try to LOAD DATA to table, and get the error.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/TEMP/Desktop/tempname.csv' INTO TABLE tempname
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(Name, ID, Birthday)
```

What do I wrong in modifying my.cnf.
I need a way that I won't get the error by default.
[image]
I modified my.cnf like that, do I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add or change local_infile in the sections

```
[mysql]
local_infile=ON
```

and

```
[mysqld]
local_infile=ON
```

Buu you have to use **ON** not 1 and you need of course to **restart the server**

Comment: It still don't work through. I also reboot my computer it doesn't work.

Comment: the error message is gone ,after adding both lines to themy.ini file under C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

Comment: windows has no cnf file it has an ini file are you shure you are editing the right file, see my folder in the previous comment